# html href link either https and http from database

Tags: html, vue.js

I just reading regarding on HTML href link and as it must include the protocols such as `https://`. I've been linking the website that is stored from database and it does not indicate whether it is `https://` or `http`. For example, the website stored in a table in database is just [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com).

Example (vue js code) `<a :href="`${website}`" target="_blank">`

Now my problem is it may redirect if that website is not an https:// but when it is https:// it has an error. Same with this code `<a :href="`https://${website}`" target="_blank">` it can redirect if it is https but if the website is not, it will not load and you need to retype in browser and add `https://`. I just want that it would redirect when the link is clicked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple :)
 Use `<a :href="//${website}" target="_blank">` instead of `<a :href="https://${website}" target="_blank">` or `<a :href="http://${website}" target="_blank">`. It will tell the browser to use the current protocol (whatever it is `http` or `https`) and also tells the browser that it's a new domain root.

Comment: I tried that one but others will redirect ```http//www.sample.com/```